# How does Anabantoideis' labyrinth function? What does it look like?

Tags: zoology, anatomy, marine-biology, respiration, ichthyology

Anabantoideis are fish with an organ that allows them to take oxygen directly from the air outside of water. However, I cannot find much on how this functions, nor can I find any clear image of what it looks like. Those I do find seems to contradict one another.

[image]

This image shows what looks like a bubble flowing into a hollow hole.

[image]

This image shows something very different, a mess of flesh, presumably where oxygen is absorbed and expelled from the gills.

[image]

This image shows a mess of flesh like before but more similar to intestines, but disconnected to the gills.

What images are most accurate, and how does the labyrinth function?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Have you tried doing an image search and looking for actual images rather than diagrams? ——— You are likely to get a better response if you [edit] your question and tell us *where* you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please also take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: @tyersome Yes, I've looked for actual images, but they are even less helpful, usually only showing external anatomy and never the real labyrinth itself.