# How do the hair cells of the inner ear contribute to most of the hypercapnic respiratory response?

Tags: general-biology

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0306452210015253

Mice with damaged ears exhibited a significantly suppressed respiratory response to carbon dioxide.

From the study:

> The mean respiratory frequency of control mice increased in response to CO2 by more than 100 breaths per minute, an increase of approximately 40–60% over their baseline values. In contrast, the ear-damaged experimental mean values increased by only 2–11%

Question: How do the inner ear hair cells contribute to most of the hypercapnic respiratory response?

Comment: Welcome Sarah. There's a [related question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/109128/how-does-anabantoideis-labyrinth-function-what-does-it-look-like), though the link may not seem immediately apparent. ;)

Comment: I don't know. Does anyone know? Did you try to find an answer? How? Please edit your question to include your research.